# Windows 10 without microsoft account causes share issue

Tags: windows, passwords, local, username

I don't want to use microsoft account on my windows computer. With it on my login and password over the local area network at home becomes the MS account/password.

If I enable local account and remove microsfot account, I can no longer access my network shares.

I thought the login/password would be the same as the Name of the computer and the password asigned to that user.. But it's not. Please help.

Also this effects Windows Remote desktop.. Ugh.. I really hope it's me who is stupid and not microsoft..

Comment: The solution is simple, share the network shares with the local user, just as you shared them with the local user account linked to the Microsoft Account.

Comment: I'm afraid I've alredy tried that.. And how do you explain the Refused remote desktop login?

Comment: Not enough info to comment on the other issue

Answer (score -1):

in system properties-> remote settings,try adding your local account to remote desktop users group.